# Tensorflow eager choose checkpoint max to keep

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm writing a process-based implementation of a3c with tensorflow in eager mode. After every gradient update, my general model writes its parameters as checkpoints to a folder. The workers then update their parameters by loading the last checkpoints from this folder. However, there is a problem.

Often times, while the worker is reading the last available checkpoint from the folder, the master network will write new checkpoints to the folder and sometimes will erase the checkpoint that the worker is reading. A simple solution would be raising the maximum of checkpoints to keep. However, tfe.Checkpoint and tfe.Saver don't have a parameter to choose the max to keep.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Not the cleanest approach, but maybe you could somehow have multiple savers and manage them yourself? (like round-robin through them or something else)

Comment: Definitely not what I'm looking for. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the [tf.train.Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) you can specify `max_to_keep`:

```
tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep = 10)
```

and `max_to_keep` seems to be present in the both [fte.Saver](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/saver.py) and it's [tf.training.Saver](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py).

I haven't tried if it works though.

Comment: unfortunately, it's not available in the tfe version. That's the problem.

Comment: Can you provide github or some other link to the version you are using?

Comment: I'm using tf version 1.10

Answer (score 0):

It seems the suggested way of doing checkpoint deletion is to use the [CheckpointManager](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/102e0de242eccb2ac4664761183a7771b0a7c7af/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_management.py#L461).

```
import tensorflow as tf
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer, model=model)
manager = tf.contrib.checkpoint.CheckpointManager(
     checkpoint, directory="/tmp/model", max_to_keep=5)
status = checkpoint.restore(manager.latest_checkpoint)
while True:
# train
  manager.save()
```

Comment: Yes, I have used this with Eager mode.